# Storing and retrieving data multiple time in locally saved json file windows phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, persistence

Hi I'm storing user profile data in items.json file locally in mobile memory.
I'm creating a folder and in that folder a file (items.json).

Here is my add_profile code.

```
    //Profile_Class is My properties Class.
    List<Profile_Class> myprofile = new List<Profile_Class>();
    string filepath;
    StorageFile myfile;
    string jsonContents;
    public add_profile()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += SignUpPage_Loaded;
    }

    //When Page load I create a folder and a file in mobile memory.
    private async void SignUpPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder myfolder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("TestFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        myfile = await myfolder.CreateFileAsync("items.json", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    }
```

Above Code Create a folder and File.
Now Next.

```
    private List<Profile_Class> buildObjectGraph()
    {
        myprofile.Add(new Profile_Class() { id = ProType.Text, address = address.Text, category = ProType.Text, color = "#31b1b0", company = company.Text, email = email.Text, facebook = facebok.Text, firstName = fname.Text, image = "Waiting", lastName = lname.Text, linkedin = linkdin.Text, mobile = phone.Text, pin = pin.Text, title = title.Text, twitter = twiter.Text, website = website.Text, work = phone_other.Text });

        return myprofile;
    }
    private async Task WritejsonAsync()
    {
        var mydata = buildObjectGraph();


        jsonContents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mydata);
        using (IRandomAccessStream mysteream = await myfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {

            using (DataWriter textWriter = new DataWriter(mysteream))
            {
                textWriter.WriteString(jsonContents);
                await textWriter.StoreAsync();
            }
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

        }
     }

    private async Task readjsonAsync()
    {

        string jsonview = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myprofile);

        using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await myfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (DataWriter textWriter = new DataWriter(textStream))
            {
                textWriter.WriteString(jsonview);

                await textWriter.StoreAsync();
            }
            MessageDialog readmesg = new MessageDialog(jsonview);
            await readmesg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

I have textboxes in xaml. And Save and read button event.

```
    private async void read_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        await readjsonAsync();
    }

    private async void Save_data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await WritejsonAsync();

    }
```

Code is fine for a single entery,,, while i come back again then every time create new file I think. HOw can I check that  if file already exist then save that in myfile,    and then new entry.

Same for read button,, when i come from another page then data lost. and  every time shows blank Json. I want that every time I come to this screen,, i can add new value in same json value and retrieve all previous. Would you please resolve this.?

Comment: are you saying that you do not know how to use the System.IO class to check if a file exist or not.. also in your code why do you have things declared but nowhere in the code you posted do you ever use the variable for example in this line ` var mydata = buildObjectGraph();` what does the buildObjectGraph method look like? are you familiar with the debugger..? start debugging the code sounds like you need to declare a static and or public variable somewhere.. in your code if everytime the page gets loaded it's re-initializing particular variables..

Comment: Yes You are right, Would you please guide me that how to check if file exists or not.?   Here in code I just chooses  OpenIfExist,,  but the result s that myfile remains empty 2nd time .

Comment: `if(File.Exists(path){ }` of course path is the variable name / path of this in your case `myfile`  assuming that `myfile has full path + file name` if you need to check that else where out side the initial load then move then change the string myfile to public string myfile = string.Empty initially or make it static

Comment: My apology for sily things. but trying to resolve this.  I have changed myfile to static,,,  I got the filepath.   if(File.Exists(path){}  what is File,  File Name does not exist in the current context?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for Check file Exist or Not

```
public async Task<bool> FileExist(string FileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var folders = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                var file = await folders.GetFileAsync(Path);
                if (file.Path != null)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return true;

            }
        }
```